# Geotool SwtMapPane draws in view but not in TitleAreDialog

Tags: geotools

I've written a very basic rcp app to show points and lines in a view. When I tried to move this code to a wizard page, it gave the error below. When I use code that simply loads and displays a shapefile, it works for both cases. How do I resolve this issue, or what should I do differently?

Jun 12, 2014 2:58:36 AM org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer fireErrorEvent
SEVERE: org/geotools/filter/text/cql2/CQLException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geotools/filter/text/cql2/CQLException

My code:

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) { //returning main for TitleAreaD
    final Composite main = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.RESIZE);
    main.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,false));
    main.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    Button b = new Button(main,SWT.NONE);
    b.setText("load");
    b.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {    
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            try {
                displayFeatures(mapPane,content);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {}
    });

    content = new MapContent();
    content.getViewport().setBounds(new ReferencedEnvelope(-180,-90,180,90,DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84));    
    mapPane = new SwtMapPane(main, SWT.NO_BACKGROUND | SWT.BORDER | SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED);
    mapPane.setMapContent(content);
    mapPane.setBackground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));

    StreamingRenderer renderer = new StreamingRenderer();
    mapPane.setRenderer(renderer);
}

private void displayFeatures(SwtMapPane mapPane, MapContent map) throws Exception {
    SimpleFeatureCollection features = createFeatureCollection();
    Style style = createStyle("shape");
    FeatureLayer layer = new FeatureLayer(features, style);
    map.addLayer(layer);
    mapPane.reset();
    mapPane.redraw();
}

private SimpleFeatureCollection createFeatureCollection() throws Exception {
    SimpleFeatureType TYPE = DataUtilities.createType("testtype","shape:Geometry:srid=4326, name:String");

    List<SimpleFeature> features = new ArrayList<>();
    SimpleFeatureCollection fc = new ListFeatureCollection(TYPE, features);
    SimpleFeatureBuilder fb = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(TYPE);

    Geometry g;
    WKTReader reader = new WKTReader();

    g = reader.read("POINT(10 10)");
    features.add(fb.buildFeature(null, new Object[]{g, "p1"}));

    g = reader.read("POINT(20 20)");
    features.add(fb.buildFeature(null, new Object[]{g, "p2"}));

    g = reader.read("POINT(30 -30)");
    features.add(fb.buildFeature(null, new Object[]{g, "p3"}));

    g = reader.read("POINT(40 -70)");
    features.add(fb.buildFeature(null, new Object[]{g, "p4"}));

    g = reader.read("LINESTRING(10 120, 40 -50)");
    features.add(fb.buildFeature(null, new Object[]{g, "line1"}));

    g = reader.read("LINESTRING(1 0, 40 30)");
    features.add(fb.buildFeature(null, new Object[]{g, "line1"}));

return fc;
}

private Style createStyle(String geomPropertyName) {
    StyleFactory sf = CommonFactoryFinder.getStyleFactory(null);
    FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2(null);

    Rule pointRule = sf.createRule();
    Function getGeomFn = ff.function("geometryType",ff.property(geomPropertyName));
    Filter pointFilter = ff.equals(getGeomFn, ff.literal("Point"));
    pointRule.setFilter(pointFilter);
    pointRule.setElseFilter(false);

    Graphic graphic = sf.getDefaultGraphic();
    graphic.graphicalSymbols().clear();
    graphic.graphicalSymbols().add(sf.getSquareMark());

    Symbolizer sym = sf.createPointSymbolizer(graphic, geomPropertyName);
    pointRule.symbolizers().add(sym);

    Rule lineRule = sf.createRule();
    lineRule.setIsElseFilter(true);
    Stroke stroke = sf.createStroke(ff.literal(Color.RED),  ff.literal(3.0f));
    Symbolizer lineSym = sf.createLineSymbolizer(stroke, geomPropertyName);
    lineRule.symbolizers().add(lineSym);

    FeatureTypeStyle fts = sf.createFeatureTypeStyle(new Rule[]{pointRule, lineRule});
    Style style = sf.createStyle();
    style.featureTypeStyles().add(fts);
    return style;
    }
```

Comment: Well, looks like a missing dependency, not sure why you get that only when putting that in a wizard page (do you really?). Anyways, did you try to follow the docs here: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/unsupported/swt/index.html  through maven you should really get what you need.

Comment: I checked the dependencies and couldn't find fault. I decided to scrap that part of the code